# Symlinks: Can't create one because file exists, cant remove it because there is no such file

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, symbolic-link, vagrant

*I posted this already on stackoverflow and it was suggested I ask here...*

I am running ubuntu 14.04 in vagrant on a windows 7 pc. I am running VirtualBox and git bash as administrator.

I've created a directory `/usr/local/npm/tones/node_modules` and I want to create a symlink to this directory in `Code/tones`.

I've been at it all evening and I think I've broken something. If I run the command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/npm/tones/node_modules Code/tones
```

I get the following error:

```
failed to create symbolic link ‘Code/tones/node_modules’: File exists
```

If I try to remove `Code/tones/node_modules` it tells me there is no such file or directory. If I add f to `sudo ln -sf` it tells me:

```
"ln: cannot remove ‘Code/tones/node_modules’: No such file or directory"
```

Yet if I try to create the link again it tells me it exists and so it goes around in circles. I can link it to a different directory, just not to `Code/tones`. I've also tried the following command which I don't really understand but got nowhere:

```
find -L . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type l -exec rm {} +
```

Another problem that occurs if I successfully create the link in a directory where I don't want it is that the linked directory appears only as a shortcut and I can't browse it so if I do get it linked to where I want it it will be no good to me. I think this is something to do with windows and VirtualBox. I did successfully link from ubuntu to the windows shared directory before but I can't seem to do it again. Any tips on this would be very welcome also.

Comment: Please add what `ls -ld /usr/local/npm/tones/node_modules Code/tones Code/tones/node_modules` says...

Comment: Where exactly in the filesystem is the Code/tones directory? your post implies it is a shared directory on the host filesystem - if so, how exactly did you set up the share?

Comment: @steeldriver yes it is a shared directory. I used a pre-existing vagrant setup (Laravel Homestead v1) and that set up the shared directory when I ran vagrant up. If I cd ~ then it can be accessed at Code/tones or /home/vagrant/Code/tones. From the same location the directory I am trying to link to is at /usr/local/npm/tones/

Comment: I'm not sure how well vboxsf supports symlinking - there appears to be an open bug ticket [making a symlink fails on a shared folder with EROFS](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085) although the error (`EROFS`) is different from yours. IMHO this is more likely a VB issue than an Ubuntu issue specifically.

Comment: The file exists/file not found part is probably not VB related though, since it's just this one link that is causing bother? There is an issue with VB and Windows alright but I think it may be a feature rather than a bug and apparently it should work once everything is run as administrator. It worked before, I have a directory symlinked as I am trying to do now, I just can't repeat it for whatever reason.